# Pandas - Why does inverting this series of booleans result in a Key Error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame very similar to the one below:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | .......... | Column Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value11 | True | value31 | ......... | ......... |
| value12 | False | value32 | ......... | ......... |
| value13 | False | value33 | ......... | ......... |
| value14 | True | value34 | ......... | ......... |

I am trying to separate it into two DataFrames, one with only the rows in which Column B is True and another with only the rows in which Column B is False.

I've tried the following:

df2 = df[df['Column B']]

df3 = df[~df['Column B']]

However, I keep getting an error when trying to assign df3, specifically,

raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"

Essentially, I want df3 to look like:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | .......... | Column Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value12 | False | value32 | ......... | ......... |
| value13 | False | value33 | ......... | ......... |

I've tried using df3 = df[df['Column B'] == False ] and that seems to work, however, this gives me PEP 8: E712 comparison to False should be 'if cond is False:' or 'if not cond:'. Any idea how I can get the negation to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

how about the following code:

a couple of options when you want to drop a couple of columns.

```py
df3 = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'Column B']
```

or probably something like below:

```py
df3 = df.drop('Column B', axis=1)
```